# Existence of elliptic curve with only one rational point over global fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a global field, does there always exist an elliptic curve $(E,e)$ over $K$, such that $E(K)=\{e\}$? (Is there an explicit way to find such a curve?)

Comment: If one could generalize the results of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7859 to an arbitary global field that should be sufficient as 100% of elliptic curves have no torsion points. I don't know any obstruction to doing this but Arul Shankar, if no one else, should know.

Comment: The answer is yes, if $K$ is a number field, see theorem 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3709v3.pdf) (and if $K=\Bbb Q$, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992668/elliptic-curve-with-only-one-point/2992695#2992695)).

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333406